# How to use Google identitytoolkit to authenticate user without getting username and password

Tags: android, kotlin, jwt, google-identity-toolkit

I'm trying to authenticate a user in my Android App using Google's [identitytoolkit](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest). The identitytoolkit is in use and provided by a third party App.

Legally speaking we're not allowed to get the user's e-mail and password. Otherwise I could do below call:

```
POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key={MY_SECRET_KEY}
{
    "returnSecureToken": true,
    "email": "my_email_address@gmail.com",
    "password": "MY_PASSWORD"
}
```

And it would return the JWT bearer token. We need some redirect URI that shows a webview into which the user can fill in the e-mail and password. How does this work? Or what are the best practices for this?